# BigQuery JDBC Nanos Negative

Tags: jdbc, google-bigquery

When trying to run a fairly basic query using the [driver provided by Simba](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/partners/simba-drivers/#current_jdbc_driver_releases_1061008), I'm running into issues where the "nanosecond" value is negative, causing `IllegalArgumentException`.

When writing a simple query that returns a `Timestamp` value, what comes back is an epoch value that is initially stored in a Double. Going through and debugging for example, I can see that the value coming back from the query is "1.498571169792E9". This corresponds to a timestamp of "Tuesday, June 27, 2017 1:46:09.792 PM" according to [epochconverter.com](https://www.epochconverter.com), which is exactly what it should be.

Continuing to step through the code, we eventually try to use `BQCoreUtils.convertUnixToTimestamp()`. Now, while I've tried to disassemble the class (thanks IntelliJ!), I can't quite figure out what's going on. It eventually tries to create a `new TimestampTz()` which is an extension of `java.sql.Timestamp`, but the value getting passed for `nanos` is negative. This of course prompts Java to throw an `IllegalArgumentException`, but I can't figure out what I need to do to avoid this.

I also don't know if there's a simpler explanation for what's going on. Ultimately though, it appears that there's a driver bug. `BQCoreUtils.convertUnixToTimestamp` doesn't properly safeguard against the `nanos` calculation being non-negative.

The dumb question then is: has anyone else experience issues querying BigQuery where Timestamp values are triggering exceptions?

Comment: Note that I've tried this with both driver versions available, and with both JDBC 4.2 and JDBC 4.1 support. All versions are causing errors for me.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** Since this is happening in Timestamp created by JDBC driver, it does appear to be a bug in JDBC driver itself. Please file it under https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:187149.

Original:
The timestamp resolution in BigQuery is microseconds, and it looks like the value you are providing is in seconds, so you should multiply it by 1000000.

Comment: BigQuery does store microseconds, yes, but when the Timestamp is created in Java after a query, the JDBC driver tries to set the `nano`s value to a non-zero number. Specifically, it sets a negative number, which causes the `IllegalArgumentException`. My apologies if that wasn't clear from the post.

Comment: @BradleeSpeice Sounds like a bug in the driver; the nanos parts of a `java.sql.Timestamp` should only contain the sub-second nano-seconds; negative values are not allowed (nor are values exceeding 999999999)

Comment: I see - sorry I got confused first, yes this is a bug, updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

With reference to [Google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63131206),

This should be resolved with versions newer than **1.1.1** of the drivers, which also addressed other timestamp-related issues.

If any issue persists, please report at [Google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63131206) they will re-open to examine.